# String literal and optional parameters don't get along in interface

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling with the following typescript compile problem:

```
const Names = {
    francesco: 'francesco'
}

export interface A {
    name: 'francesco';
    age?: number;
}

const e: A = { name: Names.francesco, age: 26 };
```

The typescript compiler outputs the following:

```
Type '{ name: string; age: number; }' cannot be converted to type 'A'.
  Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not comparable to type '"francesco"'.
(property) francesco: string
```

However, I found two ways to make the compiler stop complaining about the string literal:

**Method 1**

Make the optional parameter "age" of the interface A mandatory.

**Method 2**

Replace this line

```
const e: A = { name: Names.francesco, age: 26 };
```

with

```
const e: A = { name: 'francesco', age: 26 };
```

Does anybody have an explanation on why this is happening?

Comment: Why is your interface declaring name to be a string literal type? `name: string` in the interface seems correct to me.

Comment: @silentsod The example is a simplification of a bigger scenario where makes sense to specify the field "name" as a string literal. For instance I might want to have multiple interfaces of this kind with different string literal and different optional parameters:


interface B {
    name: "jon";
    age?: number;
    mandatory: any;
}

Comment: You're specifying the interface to have `name` with a type of `'francesco'` The interface should provide support for the general case (names are strings) and the implementations of the interface become more specific (say, an implementation where every name is `'francesco'`. What you have is essentially backwards from how interfaces are actually used.

Comment: @silentsod I understand that this example does not capture the real "why" I'm trying to do this. Nonetheless, what I'm doing is syntactically correct, and I still don't understand why typescript is giving me the error (especially why compiles correctly with method 1 and 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Names.francesco` is typed as `string` and `string` is not assignable to the type `'francesco'`. The reason for that is that a `string` is not guaranteed to be "francesco".

You probably want to change your interface to type `name` as a string:

```
export interface A {
    name: string;
    age?: number;
}
```

Or change `Names.francesco` to be typed as `'francesco'`:

```
const Names = {
    francesco: 'francesco' as 'francesco'
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This explains why the compiler works with Method 2.
But why does method 1 work?

Comment: @francesco it shouldn't work with Method 1. [I can't reproduce that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20Names%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20francesco%3A%20'francesco'%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'francesco'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20e%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20Names.francesco%2C%20age%3A%2026%20%7D%3B).

Comment: Correction: method 1 works if I cast the object to A [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20Names%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09francesco%3A%20'francesco'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09name%3A%20'francesco'%3B%0D%0A%09age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20e%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20Names.francesco%2C%20age%3A%2026%20%7D%20as%20A%3B)

Comment: @francesco the compiler gets a bit lenient when you assert—it allows assigning `string` to `"francesco"` when it's asserted.